# i want to put an image that fits the value when the data changes

Tags: angular, image

I want to put selectedsensor?.id in image src and use it, how do I do it?

```
<ul class="right-text">
  <li>{{ selectedSensor?.id || '-' }}</li>
</ul>

<img class="picture" src="assets/selectedsensor?.id.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interpolate the `id` value of your `selectedSensor` object by either using standard interpolation (with `{{}}`) or by binding the value as an input to the `src` attribute of the image tag.

Ie.

```html
<img class="picture" src="assets/{{selectedSensor?.id}}.jpg">

<!-- OR -->

<img class="picture" [src]="'assets/' + selectedSensor?.id + '.jpg'">
```